# Auto Generated Id Using Fluent NHibernate with Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, fluent-nhibernate

I am having issues inserting records using Fluent NHibernate. The code is trying to get a number from a sequence that is non-existent for the KEY field.

{"could not insert: [Class Name ][SQL: INSERT INTO Schema.TableName (KEY, ID) VALUES (hibernate_sequence.nextval, ?) returning KEY into :nhIdOutParam]"}

Of course the hibernate_sequence sequence  doesn’t exist in the database. If I do an insert using SQL Developer say:

INSERT INTO Schema.TableName (ID) VALUES (90); this works and my primary key (KEY) is auto-generated.

I know you can use a sequence to auto generate this value using GenerateBY.Sequence() but is there a way to insert the record using the SQL statment about using Fluent Nhibernate?

I have my class mapped to the primary key in my class for ex.

```c#
Id(x => x.Id, "KEY");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.  It will insert all of the fields except for the Id which will let Oracle set it for you.

```
Id(x => x.Id, "KEY").GeneratedBy.Increment();
```